# Sugar ORM specifying encryption key

Tags: android, encryption, sugarorm

I am trying to use Sugar ORM and its extension for database encryption. I am currently specifying key for encryption using manifest meta tag:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="ENCRYPTION_KEY"
        android:value="<key>" />
```

Is this safe way to store key, because I am storing it in manifest? If not, can I somehow set it programaticaly from inside of app?

EDIT: I tried [this](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/tree/sugar-cipher) guide, but it does not work, database is not encrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found solution. I used sample project from Github link above and extracted it on disk. I used Android studio to convert it to Gradle style project. I copies all my code into this new project and did all refactoring necessary for migration. After that you need to clear data if you have old instance of application, and magically it works. It seems to be configuration problem and lack of information on this branch of project.

EDIT: Also, if you want to inject key dynamically, you need to override a few classes and inject it by yourself manually.

Comment: A link to documentation or an example of how this is actually done would make a better answer.